# Cache computed component state in React.js

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'd like to know if there's any good approach to organise data processing and caching inside React components using Flux or Reflux?

For example i have a table which joins some filtered results from two stores based on props. I've been joining results inside render lately but it looks like a redundant job. It would be better to join it once `props` are changed or store event received.

Best idea i have so far is to use a mixin which rebuilds data for component only in `componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps` (and probably in `componentWillUpdate` sometimes) and put results into `this`. Maybe it would even be better to build component data in `shouldComponentUpdate` since it can also cancel rendering even when component data is complicated (with `immutable` aid), not just comparing props. But the last one looks like putting logic into wrong place.

So I thought if there's a good tool or approach for this since it looks like a common task for me. Thanks.

Comment: I think the point in using flux is to get the data handling out of the component.

Comment: @Janaka Stevens You see, it's a presentation logic. What if one component wants data sorted ascending and another one - descending? Should i add one more method for each presentation claim? And what about joining data from multiple stores? Separate store for it or one store will depend on another?

Comment: Sorting could be handled by having a get for each sort needed. ReFlux will let you combine multiple stores.

Comment: @Janaka Stevens i thought of stores as just a data storage with basic methods to retrieve all elements and a single element by id (or some very common filters). Otherwise store will grow new methods for each new dependent component. Looks like view logic goes to store.
Could you please point me to docs or example of store combination? I hardly imagine this case.

Comment: View logic is not in the store. Only data order. ReFlux is here https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs, look under "Mixins in stores". 
An example is here https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns in React.13/ReFluxWebSocket.

Comment: @Janaka Stevens i looked at the example but unfortunately understood not much. Is it like a chain of stores where each depends on the previous one and derives it's data based on this prev store?

Comment: No, it allows separation of logic buts looks like one store to the component. The store object that gets mixed in is an expansion of the base store.

Comment: @Janaka Stevens oh, thanks, that's interesting approach. But imagine when joining two tables i can't define a base store. It depends on how you look at it. Moreover imagine i have a table where two stores are joined and 3 fields are looked up in another store. Won't it lead to a overcomplicated store?

Comment: @Janaka Stevens maybe i should introduce some intermediate entity type like ViewStore which will connect stores for specific views? What do you think about this idea?

Comment: On the project I used combined stores each base.store was for one page. The mixed-in stores represented each data source. So you could think of the base.store as a ViewStore which brings the data together.

Comment: @Janaka Stevens i made a simple implementation of data caching inside component as a mixin - https://gist.github.com/nidu/47f11cfb18f96331914d. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Regarding performance I have found that the re-render count is not equal to slow response. Reacts handling of the dom negates redundant renders. You do have to be careful of using "display: 'none'" because it slows the dom render. As for duplicate data the store can decide to only emit change if there is change. Mixins are deprecated in react es6 classes so not a forward looking approach. Interesting coding though.

Comment: @JanakaStevens thanks for the info. Didn't know mixins are about to be deprecated. Just when i started to utilize them much more